# Is it possible to create a .dat file for CPLEX with java?

Tags: java, cplex

I want to generate a set of data for an optimization problem. I want to generate the data with Java and want it to be written to a .dat file that I can use with CPLEX.

Comment: If you edit your question to be more specific it might be easier to give you a concrete example. For example, do you want to read data from an Excel spreadsheet? Or, are you just looking to use plain text data?

Comment: I have a model in CPLEX for which I need some instances to analyze the structure of the solutions. But since it is a very manual task to create these instances I want to do this automatically with java. Plain text like "models ={1,2,3}; tasks = {"Task1","Task2","Task3"}; precedences = {<2, "Task1","Task2">}; ......." is enough.

Comment: The more interesting question probably is: what is the format of your data in the Java application? If you specify that we could help you in transforming it into a `.dat` file.

Comment: I do not have any data in Java yet. Therefore I can't say what format I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to generate a .dat file with Java. The .dat file is just a text file, so you can use standard techniques to create it and write out the information (e.g., run a google search for "java writing output to a file").

The section on [Data Sources](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_datasources.html) in the OPL Reference Manual explains how to format this "external" data. In addition to just creating plain text files, you can connect to external data sources such as Excel spreadsheets, databases, etc.

You should take a look at the .dat files from the examples that are included when you install CPLEX. These are located under `<CPLEX_INSTALL_DIR>/opl/examples`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a special command for creating a .dat file with Java? I couldn't find anything on Google.

Comment: No, there is no method that will create a .dat file for you automatically. You will need to write out every character in the file and make sure it is well formed.